# appendChild to array only appends to last element

Tags: javascript, dom

As you can see I am still a novice in javascript
Why is it so that you can append a Textnode only once? When you add it again somewhere else the first one disappears

I do not need a solution to a problem I was just curious what is causing this behavior. 
Example where the textnode is only added to the last element of an array:

```
function hideAdd(){
    var hide = document.createTextNode('Afbeelding verbergen');
    var afb = collectionToArray(document.getElementsByTagName('img'));  
    afb.pop();
    var divs = [];
    for (i=0; i < afb.length; i++){
        divs.push(afb[i].parentNode);

    }
    console.log(divs);
    for ( i = 0; i < divs.length;i++){
        divs[i].appendChild(hide);      
    }
}
```

This is where you use an unique textnode so it works:

```
function hideAdd(){
    var hide = []
    var afb = collectionToArray(document.getElementsByTagName('img'));  
    afb.pop();
    var divs = [];
    for (i=0; i < afb.length; i++){
        divs.push(afb[i].parentNode);
        hide[i] = document.createTextNode('Afbeelding verbergen');

    }
    console.log(divs);
    for ( i = 0; i < divs.length;i++){
        divs[i].appendChild(hide[i]);       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is the DOM is a tree, not a network. Each node can have only one parent. If you could add a node in more than one location, it would have more than one parent.

Comment: Ok I see now. If I did not put the createTextNode into a variable (not even sure if it is possible to do it without a var) it would have worked. But because I keep using the same var it changes parentnode all the time.

Thank you for this educational response.

Comment: Yes, there's no reason why you can't keep making new nodes and adding them.